# I am facing problem with puppeteer with custom fonts loading in handlebars

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose, puppeteer

The issue is, In our application, we are trying to create a resume PDF from HTML using puppeteer,nodeJS, handlebars.we are able to generate the PDF with the binded data from API,but whenever we trying to load the custom fonts to generate the PDF with custom fonts,the font-family is not loading and its not changing the fonts while generating the PDF.Any other ways to solve this or bind the custom fonts to the pdf.Can anyone help us to get out of this issue??

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?